# MS Access 2013: Intermittently Hidden Records in Form

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

My Client Project and Billing database has a form which displays projects.

On load of DB and said form I have 295 records (according to the record box at the bottom of the screen). **No filter is applied.** Only records 1-198 or 199 are actually visible in the form. The records are visible in the table and the extended table query the form pulls from. If I Refresh All then normally less records show in the table each time I refresh ex. 198, 160, 110, 80. But sometimes, a refresh all results in all records showing.

DB was created from template in Access 2013, is used via Access 2013 only, and is split into FE/BE. The Tables are on a FREENAS box which is connected via ethernet to WIFI router.  FE is on 3 user terminals which connect to network via WIFI.

I have searched for answers and think we can rule out "data entry mode" and problems with inner/outer joins.  The "recursive" and intermittent behavior seem to be important clues.

---

Update: Using Sort A-Z on customer name (A combo box select query) causes all records to appear. I am still interested in quashing this bug.

Comment: When you press the Move to the Last Record button, does the record count change?

Comment: Does your form recordsource (query) have any selection criteria that may be impacted by something ANOTHER user may be making (i.e. setting a flag/value)?

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn I don't think so. When I think through your question the only things that occur to me are standard record entries for which there would be standard cascade effects. I don't this should cause this issue.

Comment: @MattHall No, the record count does not change. If I press the Move to Last Record button or enter a record number higher than the visible record (198-199) then the screen jumps to where the visible record is present at the top and below that it is blank.

Comment: 1. Any code behind the scenes that could alter content? 2. Does the query have a sort option specified? 3. Is there a relationship with the 'sort combobox' and the recordset, or does it just run code to sort your recordset?

Comment: this could be a corrupted index according to Allen: http://allenbrowne.com/ser-47.html (take a back-up before trying the solutions listed)

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn Let me clarify.  The combobox does a select query for customer_name which comes from a query of Projects table and joins First_Name & Last_Name.  I applied sort by using the form column's filter drop down and selected A-Z. This made all records appear.

Answer (score 0):

As Matt Hall suggested, my database is corrupted. There was a duplicate in my primary table's primary key field, my indexes were buggy, I had lost my primary key, and relationships had disappeared. Now I will have to work on repairing my tables.